# xcode - phonegap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, vimeo

Does anyone know how to take the following code and make it work within phonegap?

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return(YES);
    }

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return([movieController isFullscreen]);
    }

return(NO);
}
```

I'm trying to basically allow the native ios media player to rotate to landscape mode but leave the rest of my app in portrait mode. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the your_project_name-Info.plist "Supported interface orientations" and "Supported interface orientations (iPad)"